# Xcode Development Codesigning Issue

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I recently transferred an app from one account to another.  I can submit the app to the App Store and run it in the simulator.  However, when I try to run it on my device I get this error:

```
CodeSign /Users/floydresler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_for_Dark_Tower-egxiflrzexibnghkjwvtznkhigek/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App\ for\ Dark\ Tower.app
cd "/Users/floydresler/Source Code/App for Dark Tower"
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Floyd Resler (6UFPUB2SE5)"
Provisioning Profile: "Dark Tower Dev"
                  (31912d69-5ec4-4740-a696-81ea06d3f3fb)

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 4EA262133AD193D1EB339D5E39FC055053663735 --entitlements  
/Users/floydresler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_for_Dark_Tower-egxiflrzexibnghkjwvtznkhigek/Build/Intermediates/App\ for\ Dark\ Tower.build/Debug-iphoneos/App\ for\ Dark\ Tower.build/App\ for\ Dark\ Tower.app.xcent --timestamp=none
/Users/floydresler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_for_Dark_Tower-egxiflrzexibnghkjwvtznkhigek/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App\ for\ Dark\ Tower.app

/Users/floydresler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App_for_Dark_Tower-egxiflrzexibnghkjwvtznkhigek/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App for Dark Tower.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried cleaning, deleting derived data, recreating the development provisioning profile and nothing works.  What am I doing wrong>

Comment: Have you tried to remove the application from the device and then run it again?

Comment: When I recently finished the process of transfer, it made weird behavious too. I used my device for testing app from the App Store, build version from previous Dev Account and as I wanted to run the App on simulator using another dev account and provisioning profile stuff, I realised that device reset could help. And it helped. Device holds some derived data too, like simulator on mac's drive.

Comment: Still no luck for me.  It won't even archive for a generic device now.  One thing I've noticed is that the ID shown in the error (6UFPUB2SE5) is that of the previous developer account.  I have been unsuccessful in getting to use my current developer acount ID.

Comment: Can you show your project code signing settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common cause of xcode CodeSign failing with "resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed" is additional file attributes being set, often on PNG images.

*** Before proceeding back all your files up, twice, then again, never run batch commands on your project that you dont understand.

You can clean your PNGs with:

```
find /Users/You/Project -name "*png" -exec xattr -v -c '{}' \;
```

You can repeat this for all project files with:

```
find /Users/You/Project -exec xattr -v -c '{}' \;
```

You can choose just to run this on the built project rather than your source by running it on the directory listed with the error, eg If the error is:

/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-ervhbywkvwhcpnguqaezmqqsbiqe/Build/Products/Debug/My.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

Run:

```
find /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-ervhbywkvwhcpnguqaezmqqsbiqe/Build/Products/Debug/My.app -exec xattr -v -c '{}' \;
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I believe I know which file was causing the problem.  I loaded one of my audio files into Audacity to edit it.  I'm thinking it got a resource fork when I exported it.